# Undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass (Controller#create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
NameError in CommentsController#create undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

The error on the following line. I want to save in field `user_id` (comment table) id user, which authorized in current time:

```
update_column(:user_id, user.id)
```

**Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes

  after_save :update_comments
  def update_comments
    update_column(:user_id, user.id)
    true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
  has_many :comments
end
```

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @user = User.all
    @comment = Comment.all
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

****view/_form****

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :text %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**sessions/new**

```
<%= form_tag do %>
          <div class="as"><% if flash[:alert] %>
                <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
            <% end %></div>
          <br><br>
          <fieldset>

            <legend></legend>
            <dl>
              <dt><label for="email">Log in:</label></dt>
              <dd><%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name], class: "user" %></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
              <dt><label for="password">Password:</label></dt>
              <dd><%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password], class: "password" %></dd>
            </dl>
          </fieldset>


          <fieldset class="action">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
          </fieldset>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: `Comment#user` returns `nil` (as there's no `User` assigned to this comment).

Comment: I think you should assign `current_user` and new comment (`@comment.user = current_user`) after `@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)`

Comment: If you want to make sure a comment always have a user associated, use `validates :user_id, presence: true` in the Comment model

Comment: You have same instance variable `@comment` referring to both `Comment.all` and `Comment.new(comment_params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
def create
@user = User.all
@comment = Comment.all
@comment = @current_user.comments.new(comment_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Then you need not to explicitly assign `user_id` to `comment` `after_create`. Using association it will automaticlly assign the user_id to the comment.